# ArcGIS Split Line at Point Tool splitting at intersections - faulty output?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, intersection, splitting

The screenshot below shows a 'brown_FC' of brown lines generated by [this script](https://github.com/gerry1138/Create-Perpendicular-Lines) which i want to be split at the intersection points with the 'green_FC'.
This works just fine if i take the 'brown_FC' as the script outputs it. However I need to erase a polygon FC off the 'brown_FC' before and if done so the Split Line at Point Tool fed with 'brown_FC_Erase' outputs this:
[image]

The most upper split is correct - same as with 'brown_FC' without the Erase before, the others split within the 'brown_FC_Erase' apparently. Why and how to avoid?

What I've tried so far in different combinations:

- Using the Integrate Tool as suggested in [this post](https://community.esri.com/thread/103159).
- Converting 'brown_FC_Erase' from multipart to singlepart.
- Tinkering with the search radius which only seems to worsen accuracy of the output as oppesd to when left blank.

The faultiness of the output suggests that this problem isn't just of geometrical but also of systemic nature: Instead with the intersection-points FC  (as defined in the toolbox) the lines get split where they intersect with themselves somewhere near the intersection-points FC (no matter if search radius is set to zero or left blank).

This problem leads me to the conclusion that either the tool might be somewhat corrupted or it's me overseeing some detail here...

Hopefully the latter is the case. I'm on 10.2.2 btw.

Comment: What about erase with the Brown lines as input and the green as erase features? Or using the geodatabase topology rule "Must Not Intersect With
" (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm#GUID-2154EDB0-E9C2-4B76-8F8D-94B81FE13D7B)